# Generating a list for the number of iterations of the logistic map

Tags: list-manipulation

Starting from the logistic map $x_{n+1}=r x_n(1-x_n)$, I generated a list of $10^6$ iterations for $x_0=0.3$ and $r=3.9$. This was just a random pick for the initial condition and control parameter.

```
data = {0.591838, 0.942106, 0.212713, 0.653119, 0.883563, 0.401229, 0.936953, 0.230382, 
0.691494, 0.831987, 0.545161, 0.967046, 0.124286, 0.424472, 0.952753, 0.175558, 0.564477, 
0.958787, 0.154108, 0.508398, 0.974725, 0.0960812, 0.338714, 0.873548, 0.430801, 0.956325, 
0.162893, 0.5318, 0.971056, 0.109614, 0.380635, 0.919433, 0.288897, 0.801199, 0.621189, 
0.917722, 0.294482, 0.810274, 0.599547, 0.936352}
```

These are just a few iterations from the entire list. Now what I want do to is the following. Starting from the list of successive iterations I want to generate a new list given by the number of necessary iterations such that $x_i$ has grown with $\delta$. The number of necessary iterations, $n_{itr}$, can be written as

$$n_{itr}=inf\{k;(x_{i+k}-x_{i})\geq\delta\},\hspace{5mm}\delta>0$$

With $1<i<N$ (N being the number of iterations) and $i<k<N$. I've been stuck on this for more than two days. I tried using `Position[list1,_?(#>0.25$)]` (here $\delta=0.25$) but `list1` contains elements given by $x_{i+1}-x_i$ so its not much help.

Any ideas on what I can do? Or just a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: `d = .25; Table[ i + LengthWhile[data[[i + 1 ;;]] - data[[i]], # < d &], {i, 1, 
  Length[data] - 1}]` or `d = .25; Table[
 i + LengthWhile[data[[i + 1 ;;]] - data[[i]] - d, Negative], {i, 1, 
  Length[data] - 1}]`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this function helps:

```
cf = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {i, _Integer}, {δ, _Real}},
   Block[{x0, j, n, y},
    n = Length[x];
    j = i;
    y = Compile`GetElement[x, i];
    x0 = y + δ;
    While[j < n && y < x0,
     j++;
     y = Compile`GetElement[x, j]
     ];
    If[j < n, j - i, n]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Applied to your dataset `data`, it creates

```
cf[data, Range[Length[data]], 0.25] /. Length[data] -> ∞
```

> {1, ∞, 1, 3, ∞, 1, ∞, 1, 3, ∞, 1, ∞, 1, 1, ∞, 1, 1, ∞, 1, 1, ∞, 2,
>   1, ∞, 1, ∞, 1, 1, ∞, 1, 1, ∞, 1, ∞, 1, ∞, 1, ∞, ∞, ∞}